Breaking glass effect animated sequentially
I'm trying to animate a scene where a few bullets hit a glass and cracks it. I am able to achieve the glass crack effect using cell fracture with annotation pencil. Here is what I am doing (open to feedback on the approach as well):

Create a glass pane and then do cell fracture with annotation pencil that creates a new collection of fractured glass
Hide the new fractured glass collection
Animate the bullet to hit the original glass pane
At the moment of collision hide the original glass pane and unhide the fractured glass pane collection so that it looks like the bullet cracked the glass.

This works fine with one bullet. But I want to be able to scale this for multiple bullets, say 3. How do I make it so that the cracks from bullet 1 appear first and then from bullet 2 and then bullet 3. The cracks from bullet 1 stay for bullet 2 and bullet 3. And the cracks for bullet 2 stay for bullet 3 and so on.


why can't you just make 3 objects out of the glass instead of 1?

I want to be able to scale this setup. a little bit. For example this is the window of a car where 10-15 bullets are fired. I would then have to deal with 10-15 objects, parent them and toggle visibility. I'd prefer doing it with one object only if there's a way.
